# How to return a specific row in PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, html, mysql, loops

I am trying to add a mouseover hover which basically works on the first MySQL returned query. However it will not work. It does not recognise my `IF ELSE` statement and it just returns the `ELSE` command.

My data is like

```
gallery
----------------------
id      sku         img                     types
1       454_red     front.jpg                   F
2       454_red     back.jpg                    F
3       452_red     front.jpg                   F
4       452_red     back.jpg                    F
5       452_red     a1.jpg                      S   
6       452_red     a2.jpg                      S
```

My PHP

```
<?
$imgsql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `gallery` WHERE `gallery`.`sku` = '".$r['sku']."' ORDER BY `gallery`.`type` ASC");
while($rimg=mysql_fetch_array($imgsql)){ 
?>
<? if($rimg == $rimg['0']){ ?>
        <div>
            <a href="product.php?prodref=<?=$r['sku']?>"><img src="//super.cdn.com/<?=$r['sku']?>/<?=$rimg['img']?>.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='//super.cdn.com/<?=$r['sku']?>/back.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='//super.cdn.com/<?=$r['sku']?>/<?=$rimg['img']?>.jpg'"/></a>
        </div>
    <? } else { ?>
        <div>
            <a href="product.php?prodref=<?=$r['sku']?>"><img src="//super.cdn.com/<?=$r['sku']?>/<?=$rimg['img']?>.jpg"/></a>
        </div>
    <? } ?>
<? } ?>
```

The `$r["sku"]` is called at the top of the code, this sits inside a product listing loop.

Comment: `$row['0']`...? Where'd this come from...? And what does "does not work" mean exactly?

Comment: `if($rimg == $rimg['0'])`...? How does this condition make any sense?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish because deceze is right that if statement makes no sense at all.

Comment: I want to get the first record do something, otherwise do something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it simple, then take another variable say counter or flag as below

```
<?
$count = 1;

$imgsql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `gallery` WHERE `gallery`.`sku` = '".$r['sku']."' ORDER BY `gallery`.`type` ASC");


while($rimg=mysql_fetch_array($imgsql)){ 
?>
<? if($count==1){ ?>
        <div>
            <a href="product.php?prodref=<?=$r['sku']?>"><img src="//super.cdn.com/<?=$r['sku']?>/<?=$rimg['img']?>.jpg" onmouseover="this.src='//super.cdn.com/<?=$r['sku']?>/back.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='//super.cdn.com/<?=$r['sku']?>/<?=$rimg['img']?>.jpg'"/></a>
        </div>
    <? } else { ?>
        <div>
            <a href="product.php?prodref=<?=$r['sku']?>"><img src="//super.cdn.com/<?=$r['sku']?>/<?=$rimg['img']?>.jpg"/></a>
        </div>
    <? } ?>
<? 
$count = 0;
} 

?>
```

Comment: Ahhh I was considering a loop counter too +1 ... how would I have done the MySQL count FYI

Comment: How do I return a specific Row ?

Comment: mysql_query() gives you resultset so if it have one row then you have directly use mysql_fetch_array without loop or more rows, you have to iterate it through loop